# php add a counter in while loop and return to a new line when i reach this counter

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, while-loop

this is my code:

```
$q=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscribed-team`");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){

    if($row['id-team']==$_POST["teamm"]){
        if($row['year-st']==$_SESSION["year"]){

            $p=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscription`");

            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                if($row1['id-subs']==$row['id-subs'])
                    echo"<img src='".$row1[8]."'/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now this code works fine, but it echo my results on the same line since its a loop.

i want my output to be 3 photos per line for example: 
image1 image2 image3 (jumps to line)
image4 image5 image6
and not:
image1 image2 image3 image4 image5 image6.
To be more precise i want to add a condition that when the loop reaches 3 values, it returns to a new line and continue printing the results.

Comment: Is this spelt correctly `$_POST["teamm"]` Or is this all down to a spelling error

Comment: Why can't you make the code, that include that counter? I don't understand the point of your post. Don't you know how to define variables or how to increment them?

Comment: Why does your second query not use a where clause if you are only interested in results `WHERE id-subs = '{$row['id-subs']}'`

Comment: AND DITTO the first query

Comment: i want to modify the output of the while loop, since its a loop, it will print the result in sequence, and i dont want the result to be sequential, i want 3 results per line only, its a design issue.

Comment: guys this code works fine, it prints the results, but my question is how to modify the output design.

Comment: you can try the modulo operator `$i = 0; while($row) { if($i % 3 == 0) { /* add breaker */ } $i++; }` ref: [PHP operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: never mind guys i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. not tested but should work as your need.

```
    $q=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscribed-team`");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){

            if($row['id-team']==$_POST["teamm"]){
                if($row['year-st']==$_SESSION["year"]){

                    $p=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscription`");
                    $counter = 0; 
                    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                        if($row1['id-subs']==$row['id-subs'])
                            echo"<img src='".$row1[8]."'/>";
                            $counter++; 
                            if($counter == 2){ 
                               echo "<br>";
                               $counter = 0;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. you can try. I think its because of  your nested while loop out there. otherwise that should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to actually put in line breaks.  If that is the case use this:

```
$q=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscribed-team`");
$counter = 0; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){

    if($row['id-team']==$_POST["teamm"]){
        if($row['year-st']==$_SESSION["year"]){

            $p=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscription`");
            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                if($row1['id-subs']==$row['id-subs'])
                    echo"<img src='".$row1[8]."'/>";
                    $counter++; 
                    if($counter % 3 == 0){ 
                       echo "\n";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to put in HTML breaks, try this

```
$q=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscribed-team`");
$counter = 0; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){

    if($row['id-team']==$_POST["teamm"]){
        if($row['year-st']==$_SESSION["year"]){

            $p=mysqli_query($idcon,"SELECT * FROM `subscription`");
            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                if($row1['id-subs']==$row['id-subs'])
                    echo"<img src='".$row1[8]."'/>";
                    $counter++; 
                    if($counter % 3 == 0){ 
                       echo "<br/>\n";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should avoid making iterated queries.
- You should avoid pulling more rows than you intend to use.
- You should avoid SELECTing more columns than you intend to use.
- You should apply your filtering criteria to the earliest point of data retrieval; in this case, you should use WHERE in your sql instead of an `if` in your php loop.
- You should always use a prepared statement instead of directly inserting user-supplied data into your sql.
- I don't know what column number eight is actually called, so I am going to call it `src`.
- I will urge you to make the switch to object-oriented mysqli syntax because it is simpler and more concise than procedural syntax.
- The result set object is iterable, so it can be fed directly into the `foreach()`.
- To create an html line break between every three rows, echo `<br>` if `$i` is not zero and is evenly divisible by 3.

Recommended Code: (untested)

```
$sql = "SELECT `src`
        FROM `subscription` AS s
        JOIN `subscribed-team` AS st ON s.`id-subs` = st.`id-subs`
        WHERE st.`id-team` = ?
          AND st.`year-st` = ?";

$stmt = $idcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["teamm"], $_SESSION["year"]);
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $i => $row) {
    if ($i && $i % 3 === 0) {
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo '<img src="' . $row['src'] . '"/>';
}
```